# Jquery when Selecting Autocomplete, fill another textbox

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I have autocomplete, what i want when i select autocomplete, another textbox filled with related field in database table. this is my codes, please help me.

This is my controller

```
public function get_autocomplete()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
            $result = $this->MdlAutocomplete->search_penjual($_GET['term']);
            if (count($result) > 0) {
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    $arr_result[] = $row->nama;
                }

                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
        }
    }
```

And This is my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#penjual').autocomplete({
        source: "<?php echo site_url('lelang/get_autocomplete'); ?>"
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Details you have provided isn't enough to understand what you exactly wants to do and where? Please add some more code where you wish to show your desire output.

Comment: thank you for your advices, im newbie here